# Compiz annotate not working in fullscreen mode

Tags: compiz

Compiz annotate not working in fullscreen mode. If I annotate/draw while in full screen mode nothing happens. Then when I exit the fullscreen mode all my annotations appear.

I tested Gedit and Chrome so far.

How can I enable annotations to work while in fullscreen mode?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Christopher Townsend said:

> What I think is happening here is that most fullscreen windows are unredirected meaning they basically get access to the GPU for performance. In these cases, no other window can be drawn which is what you are seeing.
>
> The good news is that we have a way to whitelist fullscreen windows to not unredirect or turn it off altogether. In CCSM, go to Composite and either uncheck "Unredirect Fullscreen Windows" or add your particular application to the Unredirect Match.

Source: https://bugs.launchpad.net/compiz/+bug/1366609/comments/6

Answer (score 1):

install Ubuntu 12.04.2, uncheck download upgrade during installation, and do not update after install. then plugin Annotation of compiz works in full screen mode.

I am trying Ubuntu 14.04.1 now, and Annotation works in full screen mode of VLC (the marks is over the running video), but not work with image view (toggled by F11) and VirtualBox (vm in fullscreen)

I dig a bit further, this problem begins with Ubuntu 12.04.3. early versions are free of this bug.

Comment: Thanks for opening this issue on Launchpad. https://bugs.launchpad.net/compiz/+bug/1366609